# SQL Server : how to update table b , when a single row is updated in table a?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have created a SQL Server trigger which is supposed to add a kill to a doctor whenever one of his patients changes state to "killed". But I don't know how to just get the one row that is updated. As it looks now, the doctor get patientKilled++ for every patient he ever had before as well.

How can I solve this ?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PatientKilled] 
ON [dbo].[Patient]
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Doctor 
    SET PatientsKilled += 1 
    FROM Doctor d 
    INNER JOIN inserted p ON d.DoctorId = p.DoctorId 
    WHERE p.PatientState = 'Killed' 
END
```

Comment: join the inserted table. In Triggers you have access to 2 system tables named Inserted and Deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word “kill” implies the doctor is homicidal but disregarding that issue this should do what you need.

You should check the previous state and only increment the counter if this is changed. I have assumed that “Killed” is a permanent state so no need to add logic to decrement. You should consider if you need that.

```
WITH p AS
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NewKills, 
               I.DoctorId
FROM INSERTED I JOIN DELETED D
ON I.PatientId = D.PatientId
WHERE I.PatientState = 'Killed'  
    AND (D.PatientState <> 'Killed' OR D.PatientState IS NULL)
GROUP BY I.DoctorId
)
UPDATE d
SET PatientsKilled += NewKills
FROM Doctor d 
    INNER JOIN p ON d.DoctorId = p.DoctorId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [AD17_Hospital]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[PatientKilled]    Script Date: 2017-10-21 19:51:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PatientKilled] ON [dbo].[Patient]
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE Doctor 
SET PatientsKilled (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Patients WHERE DoctorID = INSERTED.DoctorID AND PatientState = 'Killed')
FROM Doctor d 

END
```

Comment: No, added 2... have no idea whats happeing.. even when he killed 3 patients before it added 2 and not 4...

Comment: Is there a way to just set patientskilled to the number of patients with the state = "killed" every time a patientstate is changed to killed instead? if you understand what i mean

Comment: Did not work at all unfortunately, but thanks for taking the time